# POD Formatting For Soft And Hard Cover

Tags: self-publishing, print-on-demand

I have a finished manuscript and am ready to self-publish. I will go with IngramSpark and CreateSpace and would like to offer both soft and hard cover versions of my book.

Question: Should I supply two different PDFs for soft and hard versions? The books are the same trim size.

I've read the documentation and there are some variations in file specs but nothing about if two different files should be supplied.

Comment: What is POD? (Maybe write it out in the question header.)

Comment: POD=Print On Demand

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked CreateSpace only supported soft cover, so it's something of a moot point there.

In any case, you will have to create two PDFs for at least one reason: You must have a different ISBN for a hard cover edition than for a soft cover edition, and you normally include the ISBN on the copyright page of the book.

Comment: I would include both ISBNs on the copyright page: